# Different size sprites in sprite sheet

Tags: python, pygame

I'm loading a spritesheet in Python and Pygame which contains sprites of different sizes. I can display them but the character isn't standing still even though it's the idle animation as some are larger and therefore force the character further right.

My code for this is:

```
class Hero(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Hero class"""
    def __init__(self, position):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.load_frames()
        self.image = self.img_list[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = position
        self.pause = 1
        self.delay = 1
        self.index = 0
    def load_frames(self):
        spritesheet = pygame.image.load("spritesheet.png").convert()
        self.img_list = []
        self.size_list = [(26,32),(27,31),(29,30), (31,30), (33,31), (34,31), (36,32), (38,33), (34,33), (34,33), (32,32), (27,31), (25,30), (24,30), (23,31), (21,31), (20,32), (20,33), (22,33), (24,33)]
        self.offset = ((14,6), (42,7), (72,8), (104,8), (138,7), (174,7), (211,6), (250,5), (291,5), (328,5), (365,5), (400,6), (430,8), (458,8), (485,7), (511,7), (535,5), (558,4), (581,4), (606,4))
        for i in range(20):
            tmp_img = pygame.Surface(self.size_list[i])
            tmp_img.blit(spritesheet, (0,0), (self.offset[i], self.size_list[i]))
            self.img_list.append(tmp_img)
    def update(self):
        if self.delay == self.pause:
            if self.index == len(self.img_list):
                self.index = 0
            oldcenter = self.rect.center
            self.image = self.img_list[self.index]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = oldcenter
            self.delay = 0
            self.index += 1
        self.delay += 0.5
```

How would I center the character even though the sprite sizes are different? My first thought was somehow making a reference point which I manually position but this seems a bit slow, are there better ways or if this is a good way how would I go about implementing it?

Comment: why does your spritesheet have have images of the same character in differen sizes? Instead of trying to correct that in the code, i would just edit the spritesheet to have the images of the same size.

Comment: The code you posted looks good, always use the same center. Isn't it working for you?

Comment: No my rect is changing size from smaller to larger as my characters tail moves, which pushes the body right. I could change the spritesheet but I would rather figure out a way in code so that I can get them working quicker. What I want is the rect growing larger from the old rects size, so expanding outwards instead of from the top left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When positioning the sprite do:

```
sprite.rect.center = player.center_pos
```

If you have to calculate the center_pos of the player do this:

```
player.center_pos[0] = player.pos[0] + player.sprite.get_size()[0] / 2
player.center_pos[1] = player.pos[1] + player.sprite.get_size()[1] / 2
```